# How to Remove XML, doctype and top-level namespace declarations from XML response string?

Tags: php, xml

I have the following response string from an API call with returns XML. I need to remove the doctype and other top-level namespace declarations from the response to parse the value in to a SimpleXMLElement. I tried to create a string regex expression and it works but is there a more general way to remove the declarations from the response?
Here's the response string and the code that I used to remove the declarations:

Code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$retValue = curl_exec($ch);          
curl_close($ch);

return json_encode(array("response" => $retValue));
```

Resulting JSON Encoded XML Response

```
{
  "response": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE list_tests [\n<!ENTITY % ext1 PUBLIC \"-\/\/W3C\/\/LIST TESTS for XHTML\/\/EN\" \"http:\/\/www.test.com\/api\/list_tests.ent\">\n<!ENTITY % ent1 PUBLIC \"-\/\/W3C\/\/ENTITIES for XHTML\/\/EN\" \"http:\/\/www.test.com\/api\/xhtml.ent\">\n%ext1;\n%ent1;\n]>\n<list_tests  xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.test.com\/schema\">\n  <campaigns>\n    <campaign_code>1234567<\/campaign_code>\n    <campaign_name>Test1<\/campaign_name>\n  <\/campaigns>\n  <campaigns>\n    <campaign_code>1234567<\/campaign_code>\n    <campaign_name>Test2<\/campaign_name>\n  <\/campaigns>\n  <campaigns>\n    <campaign_code>1234567<\/campaign_code>\n    <campaign_nameTest3<\/campaign_name>\n  <\/campaigns>\n  <campaigns>\n    <campaign_code>1234567<\/campaign_code>\n    <campaign_name>Test4<\/campaign_name>\n  <\/campaigns>\n  <campaigns>\n    <campaign_code>1234567<\/campaign_code>\n    <campaign_name>Test5<\/campaign_name>\n  <\/campaigns>\n  <campaigns>\n    <campaign_code>1234567<\/campaign_code>\n    <campaign_name>Test6<\/campaign_name>\n  <\/campaigns>\n  <campaigns>\n <campaign_code>1234567<\/campaign_code>\n    <campaign_name>Test7<\/campaign_name>\n  <\/campaigns>\n<\/list_tests>\n\n"
}
```

Using the following code I am able to remove the doctype and the other declarations.

```
$retValue = str_replace('<!DOCTYPE list_account_campaigns [
    <!ENTITY % ext1 PUBLIC "-//W3C//LIST ACCOUNT CAMPAIGNS for XHTML//EN" "http://www.mongoosemetrics.com/api/list_account_campaigns.ent">
    <!ENTITY % ent1 PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES for XHTML//EN" "http://www.mongoosemetrics.com/api/xhtml.ent">
    %ext1; %ent1; ]>', '', $retValue);

return json_encode(array("response" => $retValue));
```

Resulting Desired Response

```
{
  "response": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<list_tests  xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.test.com\/schema\">\n  <campaigns>\n    <campaign_code>1234567<\/campaign_code>\n    <campaign_name>Test1<\/campaign_name>\n  <\/campaigns>\n  <campaigns>\n    <campaign_code>1234567<\/campaign_code>\n    <campaign_name>Test2<\/campaign_name>\n  <\/campaigns>\n  <campaigns>\n    <campaign_code>1234567<\/campaign_code>\n    <campaign_nameTest3<\/campaign_name>\n  <\/campaigns>\n  <campaigns>\n    <campaign_code>1234567<\/campaign_code>\n    <campaign_name>Test4<\/campaign_name>\n  <\/campaigns>\n  <campaigns>\n    <campaign_code>1234567<\/campaign_code>\n    <campaign_name>Test5<\/campaign_name>\n  <\/campaigns>\n  <campaigns>\n    <campaign_code>1234567<\/campaign_code>\n    <campaign_name>Test6<\/campaign_name>\n  <\/campaigns>\n  <campaigns>\n <campaign_code>1234567<\/campaign_code>\n    <campaign_name>Test7<\/campaign_name>\n  <\/campaigns>\n<\/list_tests>\n\n"
}
```

Is there a more general way to remove the namespace declarations from the curl response aside from using regex? Thanks.

Comment: the xml is not correct. It begins with `<list_tests` and ends with `</list_account_campaigns>`

Comment: my bad, I changed the list_account_campaigns to list_tests before putting them here. I just edited the post now.

Comment: Why would you JSON-encode an XML document? Also, it might be useful to include an example of the XML you get from the curl call and what the resulting XML you want to provide look like.  My guess is that XML/DOM manipulation is the proper approach here.

Comment: I just json encoded it because i was calling that function from javascript so I dumped it in the console.log(). Regardless, I was going to manipulate it in php before I pass the resulting object back to JS. that's why I needed to remove the namespace declarations.